# convergence $a_{n+1}-a_n$ implies convergence of $a_{n}/n$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Prove that if $\lim _{n \to \infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=L$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=L$.

My idea is: $\forall \varepsilon >0$ $\exists N_{\varepsilon}$ such that $\forall n > N_{\varepsilon}$ $$L-\varepsilon < a_{n+1}-a_n<L+\varepsilon$$  so
$$|a_n - a_m|=\left|a_{n}-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-2}- \cdots - a_{m} \right|$$
$$(n-m)(L-\varepsilon)<a_n-a_m < (n-m)(L- \varepsilon)$$
but  I don't know how conclude this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Apply Cesaro to $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$.

Comment: @StefanLafon thank you, that was enough!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ({X_{n + 1}} - {X_n}) = c$ implies $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } {{{X_n}} \over n} = c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556194/lim-limits-n-to-infty-x-n-1-x-n-c-implies-lim-limits-n) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%20_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D(a_%7Bn%2B1%7D-a_n)%3DL%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Ba_n%7D%7Bn%7D%3DL%24&p=1). FYI, it also included the fairly related [Searching for an example of sequence $(u_n)$ such that](/q/2590852).